# How to hide a specific fieldset with CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I need to hide the fieldset with the ID

```
<fieldset class="insurance-options" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1512143898049_574">
                    <ul id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1512143898049_573">
                        <li id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1512143898049_572">
                            <div class="l" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1512143898049_571"><label for="_wizcarinsurance_WAR_wizportlet_:j_idt236:greenCard" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1512143898049_570"><input id="_wizcarinsurance_WAR_wizportlet_:j_idt236:greenCard" type="checkbox" name="_wizcarinsurance_WAR_wizportlet_:j_idt236:greenCard" class="do-eec-product-click trigger-greenCard" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'@form',{'onevent':WizInsurance.reInitWithSidebarReload})">
        <h3 class="with-icon">
            <span>Zelena karta</span><div class="tool-tip do-eec do-eec-product-detail-impression-tooltip trigger-greenCard" data-original-title="" title="">
                <span class="ico ico-info"></span>
                <div class="tooltip-content"><p><strong>Zelena karta</strong>&nbsp;je mednarodno potrdilo o zavarovanju avtomobilske odgovornosti. Zagotavlja zavarovalno kritje v obsegu, ki ga določa pristojni zakon o obveznem zavarovanju avtomobilske odgovornosti v obiskani državi. Zeleno karto potrebujejo vozniki, ki nameravajo potovati v tujino. Predložiti jo je potrebno na meji in v primeru prometne nesreče.</p>
                </div></div>
                </fieldset>
```

And many more, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/m2qcc19h/ even with the incomplete HTML

Comment: As @j08691 says, `#yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1512143898049_574 { display: none; }` should do it. Are there any other selectors that are overriding that one?

Comment: Not sure, this is the whole code, ok just found out I can't paste it here, will edit my original post

Comment: Still works https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/y0kp84x7/

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that the ID of the fieldset is changing with each refresh of the page. Is this out of scope of CSS now?

Comment: @ReneStefancic is the class changing as well? If not then you can probably target that.

Comment: @ReneStefancic There are many other ways to uniquely select html elements to style outside of ID if it keeps changing.

Comment: unfortunately no, the class is "insurance-options" but it's the same for multiple elements and I don't want to remove them all

Comment: @zgood could you point me in the right direction? I'm a noob in all of this.

Comment: @ReneStefancic Well given the markup `fieldset.insurance-options` would work if you didnt have any other `fieldset`'s with that class. You can also target just part of the id if just part of the id is changing (i.e. `fieldset[id^="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1"]` which reads "find a fieldset whose id _starts with_ "yui_patched_v3_11_0_1". Also if something about the section is unique you could use that - like if its the only `fieldset` nested in a div with the id `#foo` just use `#foo fieldset.insurance-options`. But we would have to see more of the HTML to determine that.

Answer (score 1):

As other have pointed out, your first attempt was correct.

```
#yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1512143898049_574 { display: none; }
```

If this isn't working, the most likely cause is that a stronger selector is overriding your style. The quick-and-dirty fix would be to add `!important` to the rule.

```
#yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1512143898049_574 { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, yet it still doesn't work. What should I be looking for?

Comment: First thing to check is the dev tools. Right-click the fieldset and click "Inspect Element" - that will show you the styles that are being applied. See if your `display: none;` style is in there and if it's being overridden by anything.

Comment: Ok, I've found the problem, the ID of the fieldset is changing with each refresh of the page. I'm guessing this is beyond the scope of CSS, and with that my abilities to edit the page.

Comment: That's probably the case. If there's a part of it that never changes, you can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) but you might end up with a few things being matched instead of just the one. I think that you'll struggle to do what you want to do if you can't modify the markup to add something like a class or constant ID to the fieldset